# Is mean and average occupation number same?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, quantum-statistics

In Bose distribution we have formula to find number of particles in quantum state .Is mean occupation number and average occupation number same ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mean and average are usually used as synonyms.